# Getting 0x800C0005 System error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services

The following code is used to call a web service from SQL Server:

```
Declare @Object as Int; 
Declare @ResponseText as VARCHAR(MAX);

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'GET','http://localhost/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld?name=xyz', false;

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send';

EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

Create table #tmp(dt varchar(max))

insert into #tmp 
    exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'ResponseText' --,@strLine OUtPUT

Select dt from #tmp -- single column/single row.

Drop Table #tmp -- clean up

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object;
```

But I am getting below error:

> 0x800C0005    msxml3.dll  System error: -2146697211

Any pointers ...?

Comment: Which line gives that error?

Comment: Sorry i too Don't know... @PawełDyl

Comment: Try debugging or remove lines - try with 3 top, then try with 4 top etc.

Comment: Try to use `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` instead of `MSXML2.XMLHTTP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two (2) ways to fix Msxml3 Dll 0x800c0005 System Error Error:

Advanced Computer User Solution (manual update):
1) Start your computer and log on as an administrator.
2) Click the Start button then select All Programs, Accessories, System Tools, and then click System Restore.
3) In the new window, select "Restore my computer to an earlier time" option and then click Next.
4) Select the most recent system restore point from the "On this list, click a restore point" list, and then click Next.
5) Click Next on the confirmation window.
6) Restarts the computer when the restoration is finished.

Novice Computer User Solution (completely automated):
1) Download (Msxml3 Dll 0x800c0005 System Error) repair utility.
2) Install program and click Scan button.
3) Click the Fix Errors button when scan is completed.
4) Restart your computer.

[More details](http://thewinwiki.org/msxml3-dll-0x800c0005-system-error/)